# Why is my python process getting down-prioritized/throttled?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having this weird issue where it seems my python process gets throttled or down-prioritized in some scheduling when run on a remote machine, running so slow its almost un-useable.

The remote machine is running ubuntu with 24 cores and 48 threads, and python version 3.10.12.

I have tried starting the script in a few different ways, ie

```
python3 -m my_submodule.my_script args
taskset -c x,y python3 my_submodule.my_script args
taskset -c x python3 my_submodule.my_script args
```

(where x,y are thread numbers on the same core)

and they all generally seem to start out reasonable when looking in htop view, with useage hitting almost 100% on designated threads, but then quickly drops off in usage and the script running speed slows down significantly. Any thoughts on what is causing this? This problem generally arises when running scripts in the submodule (though not always) and not when running arbitrary scripts in the main repository. The issue is also seemingly random where sometimes it runs with expected speed all the way through.

There are no fancy multiprocessing or multithreading stuff going on in the submodule script, it is basically a for loop processing and inserting data in a local hdf5 database.

Comment: This is out of my wheelhouse, but I'm not sure there's enough info here to really diagnose the problem, so you should make a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.